# Step over a C++ throw statement in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, gdb, throw

When debugging a C++ program with the GNU GDB debugger, I can step over the next line of code with the GDB command:

```
next
```

However, when an exception is thrown within that next line, like e.g.

```
throw SomeException();
```

then GDB continues to run until the next breakpoint instead of stopping within the first line of the `catch` block.

Is this a bug within GDB, or am I just using the wrong command?

I'm using GDB version 7.7 on [MinGW32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) / Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux this works properly.  In particular there is a special debugging marker (either a function or an "SDT probe", depending on how things were built) in the low-level unwinding code that is used when an exception is thrown. GDB puts a breakpoint at this spot.  When this breakpoint is hit, GDB examines the target stack frame of the `throw` and, if it is above the `next`ing frame, puts a temporary breakpoint at the target of the `throw`.

This required some changes in GDB, but also some changes in the C++ runtime in order to inform GDB about `throw`s.  As far as I know, nobody has ever done the work to port this code to MinGW. Maybe it could be done by modifying the appropriate `unwind-mumble.c` file in the GCC sources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. So this means there won't be an easy fix for MinGW, right? Too bad, as this actually hinders effective C++ debugging when exceptions are used.

Comment: It might not be too hard, but it's difficult to be sure without digging into the relevant gcc sources.