# Stepping over a function with a throw statement inside in gdb doesn't take me to catch statement

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, try-catch, throw

I'm trying to step through a C++ program. It throws an exception in a lower layer, but I'm unable to have the gdb debugger take me to the catch statement. One workaround is to register catch-points with `(gdb) catch catch` but it feels clunky to have to remember to always do that, and it will cause the program to halt at each chain of catch-statements in the lower layers.

Here's a repro to illustrate my point. For this program compiled with `g++ foo.cpp -g -o foo`..

```
#include <cstdio>

void f() {
    throw 42;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try {
        throw 42;
        //f();
        printf("after throw\n");
    } catch (...) {
        printf("in catch stmt\n");
    }
    printf("after try-catch stmt\n");
}
```

.. Gdb works as I expect: When I step over the throw statement, the next statement is the catch.

```
$ gdb -q foo
Reading symbols from foo...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x912: file foo.cpp, line 9.
Starting program: /home/dannas/foo
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd88) at foo.cpp:9
9               throw 42;
(gdb) next
12          } catch (...) {
(gdb)
13              printf("in catch stmt\n");
(gdb)
in catch stmt
12          } catch (...) {
```

But if I replace the `throw 42` statement in `main` with `f()`, then the program will end if I step over `f()`.

```
$ gdb -q foo
Reading symbols from foo...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x912: file foo.cpp, line 10.
Starting program: /home/dannas/foo

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd78) at foo.cpp:10
10              f();
(gdb) n
in catch stmt
after try-catch stmt
[Inferior 1 (process 32522) exited normally]
```

Versions:

```
 $ gdb --version
 GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
 $ gcc --version
 gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
```

Tom Troey says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601424/582010:

> [...] there is a special debugging marker (either a function or an "SDT
> probe", depending on how things were built) in the low-level unwinding
> code that is used when an exception is thrown. gdb puts a breakpoint
> at this spot. When this breakpoint is hit, gdb examines the target
> stack frame of the throw and, if it is above the nexting frame, puts a
> temporary breakpoint at the target of the throw.

## Question

Is gdb unable to know which line it will execute next? The quote above seems to suggest that gdb makes an effort to figure out which is the next statement based on available catch handlers? Is there a way to make the debugger behave as I expect: "gdb stops at the next executed statement in a function when stepping"?

Comment: A _throw_ is not a goto to a defined address, during the _throw_ the instances supported by local variables are deleted up to may be reach a possible _catch_, so a lot of code can be executed and gdb cannot know even if there is a catch.

Comment: @bruno In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595588/gdb-step-over-throw-statement-in-c, Tom Troey says that gdb makes an effort to inspect the catch handlers (atleast that's how I interpret it). I would assume that it would happen prior to the stack unwinding. Care to expand your comment to an answer?

Comment: Could not reproduce on Fedora 29 with `f();` uncommented with gdb 8.2 and gcc 8.3.1.

Comment: @ks1322 That's good news! I've edited my question to include the version of gcc as well. Ubuntu 18.10 so I'm a few steps behind. (I assume that you did remove the `throw 42;` line as well when you tested. If so, then I guess I'll just have to update my OS.

Comment: I waited to be at home to not be under an old RedHat, on a raspbian / ubuntu 16.10 calling _f_ the _throw_ is not _stepable_, these gcc are too old